# How to adjust the size of the dots in the legend of a Seaborn scatterplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, legend, scatter-plot

I know that the `s` argument in searbons `scatterplot` allows to control the size of the dots. For instance:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Y_LOCATION'] = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4]
df['X_LOCATION'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1]
df['VALUE'] = [-0.45, -0.14, -0.12, -0.36, -0.48, -0.20]
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(40,20)})
sns.set(font_scale=2)
sns.scatterplot(df.Y_LOCATION, df.X_LOCATION, df.VALUE, s=800, palette = "Greens_r")
```

[image]

However, this parameter appears to have no impact on the size of the dots shown in the legend. How can these be adjusted?

Comment: The example code gives me the error `TypeError: scatterplot() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 3 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given`.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe we are using different versions of scatter plot? I am using 0.11.1. Maybe try: `sns.scatterplot(x = df.Y_LOCATION, y = df.X_LOCATION, hue = df.VALUE, s=800, palette = "Greens_r")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the size of those dots by getting the handles of the dots in the legend, and calling `set_sizes()` on them. They are [36] by default, by multiplying that by 10, it increases the area (not diameter) by a factor of 10.

Example:

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(x = df.Y_LOCATION, y = df.X_LOCATION, hue = df.VALUE, s=800, palette = "Greens_r")
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
for dot in handles:
    dot.set_sizes(dot.get_sizes() * 10)
plt.legend(handles, labels)
```

See also: [How to adapt too large dot sizes in a seaborn scatterplot legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60886965/how-to-adapt-too-large-dot-sizes-in-a-seaborn-scatterplot-legend)

Documentation on PathCollection.set_sizes(): https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection.set_sizes

Comment: Spot on! Thanks for your detailed answer @Nick ODell.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this..

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(4, 2))
sns.scatterplot(np.random.rand(1000, 2), s=1)
plt.legend(fontsize=8, markerscale=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @justin4480: it solves my issue in a very straightforward manner.